# Is it possible to restrict a git push based on its size?

Tags: git, size, hook, push

I have a git repository on the remote server. When my users do "git push" to this remote server, I want to restrict the push based on it's size. Let us say, if the size of the push exceeds 100MB, the push should be stopped.

I am trying to do this using the pre-receive hook on the remote git repository.

There are related questions with some solutions in stackoverflow.com. I tried them. But, they all are not working from the remote repository.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I guess an interesting question would be why do you need to do this?

Comment: To check if the git remote repository will exceed the quota limit by the push.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. By the time the pre-receive and update hooks run, the pack (all the data) has already been received. All that's left to do is update refs, and that's what the hook allows you to abort. From the manpage:

> Just before starting to update refs on the remote repository, the pre-receive hook is invoked.

And there's an identical statement about the update hook.

I'm not even sure if, for a general transport mechanism, even `git receive-pack` knows the final size of everything it's going to receive.

What problem are you actually trying to solve, though? Save users from time-consuming pushes ? (They can cancel them themselves; it's pretty obvious from the user's side.) Keep disk space under control on the remote? In most cases, you can probably just restrict access to users you can trust not to mess it up, and deal with exceptions manually.

If you absolutely have to do this, the only way you'd really be able to do it is by wrapping push on the user's side, so that they run `my-push` which somehow estimates the size of what they're about to push, and decides whether to actually push - but then you're back to trusting users, since if they don't use that wrapper, they can push what they'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jefromi. I am trying to check if the git remote repository will exceed the quota limit by the push.